# HDD thumping noise

Tags: hard-drive, computer-building, desktop-computer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hard drive making a weird noise](https://superuser.com/questions/60309/hard-drive-making-a-weird-noise)

My 2TB Western Digital Caviar Green is making this thumping noise. The thumps repeat about every 2 seconds and occasionally go away altogether.

It passed WD's own diagnostic tool, but I am still wondering: is it dying?

Comment: If it's making noise, it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

If this thumping noise is similar to what you hear when you are starting your computer, then your hdd is dying, or perhaps you have issues with your power supply/cables. Try to see if you can get the same behavior, installing the hdd into another computer.
Usually hdds have the same number of platters. The density at which they can store data, makes the capacity difference.

Comment: it sounds like a gremlin is trapped inside my case.